# Pycharm: Hotkey to go to the file window

Tags: pycharm, hotkeys

How can I go back to my file edition when I am in a tool window (Console, Project, ...) in pycharm.

I see shortcut for the tool windows (CMD+1, CMD+4, ...), but I cannot go back to my file edition without closing the actual tool window and without the mouse.

Is there a hotkey that exists to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Escape key. not work for console.
2. "alt + 2"  twice.